# How do I mount USB devices in opensuse?

Tags: mount, usb-storage, opensuse

I have tried:

- Mount `/dev/sdb` `/mnt`
- Mount `/dev/sdb /media`
- Mount `/dev/sdb1`

And so on

I have also tried reformatting in partition editor. I unplugped and plugged it back in ,
but I can't find the device anywhere except for in partition editor using openSUSE.

With a stubborn device like this, how can I mount it by command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually just `mount /dev/sdb1 <some empty directory>` (as root) should work - if not, look at the output of `dmesg` and see if there are any errors listed.

Comment: @user: for some reason, plugging in a different device and then replugging the first device worked. thanks for the dmesg tip

Answer (score 4):

use dmesg to see if it has been recognized, and if it has dmesg should show what device and partition it sees, then mount it using whatever partition it shows...

ie if dmesg shows /dev/sdb1 then mount /dev/sdb1 (remember to sudo).

Example from dmesg..

```
[15071568.063623] scsi22 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[15071568.063788] usb-storage: device found at 62
[15071568.063791] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[15071573.059741] usb-storage: device scan complete
[15071573.068610] scsi 22:0:0:0: Direct-Access     EasyDisk USB FLASH DISK   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[15071573.077710] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] 64000 512-byte hardware sectors (33 MB)
[15071573.086955] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[15071573.086958] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[15071573.086960] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
[15071573.096571] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] 64000 512-byte hardware sectors (33 MB)
[15071573.105818] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[15071573.105821] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[15071573.105823] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
[15071573.105825]  sdg: sdg1
```

In this case you would..

`> sudo mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt`

Answer (score 1):

do you see your USB drive under ouptput of

```
lsusb
```